# Why is LLVM llc compiler throwing error for instruction number?

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I built LLVM and installed clang in my docker to compile a C program to LLVM IR and from LLVM IR to assembly. When I try to compile the .ll file to .s through llc, I get the following error:

```
llc: error: llc: check.ll:12:3: error: instruction expected to be numbered '%5'
  %4 = alloca i32, align 4
```

I looked at other queries regarding this but they all had problems when the code had a ret statement, which isn't my case. Any specific reason why it would throw this error?

Here is my IR code:

```
; ModuleID = 'check.c'
source_filename = "check.c"
target datalayout = "e-m:e-i64:64-f80:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-pc-linux-gnu"

@.str = private unnamed_addr constant [3 x i8] c"hi\00", align 1
@.str.1 = private unnamed_addr constant [3 x i8] c"uh\00", align 1

; Function Attrs: noinline nounwind optnone uwtable
define i32 @main(i32, i8**) #0 {
  %3 = alloca i32, align 4
  %4 = alloca i32, align 4
  %5 = alloca i8**, align 8
  %6 = alloca i32, align 4
  %7 = alloca i32, align 4
  store i32 0, i32* %3, align 4
  store i32 %0, i32* %4, align 4
  store i8** %1, i8*** %5, align 8
  store i32 3, i32* %6, align 4
  store i32 2, i32* %7, align 4
  %8 = load i32, i32* %6, align 4
  %9 = load i32, i32* %7, align 4
  %10 = icmp eq i32 %8, %9
  br i1 %10, label %11, label %13

; <label>:11:                                     ; preds = %2
  %12 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @.str, i32 0, i32 0))
  br label %15

; <label>:13:                                     ; preds = %2
  %14 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([3 x i8], [3 x i8]* @.str.1, i32 0, i32 0))
  br label %15

; <label>:15:                                     ; preds = %13, %11
  %16 = load i32, i32* %3, align 4
  ret i32 %16
}

declare i32 @printf(i8*, ...) #1

attributes #0 = { noinline nounwind optnone uwtable "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-jump-tables"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }
attributes #1 = { "correctly-rounded-divide-sqrt-fp-math"="false" "disable-tail-calls"="false" "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "no-signed-zeros-fp-math"="false" "no-trapping-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "target-cpu"="x86-64" "target-features"="+fxsr,+mmx,+sse,+sse2,+x87" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.module.flags = !{!0}
!llvm.ident = !{!1}

!0 = !{i32 1, !"wchar_size", i32 4}
!1 = !{!"clang version 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 (tags/RELEASE_600/final)"}
```

Comment: I ran llc on the code you pasted and don't get any error message.

Comment: oh wow okay. I did build llvm after adding an instruction, is there a possibility that that would have caused this issue?

Comment: You modified LLVM? Then at least [run LLVM's tests](https://llvm.org/docs/TestingGuide.html). `ninja check-llvm`, better yet, write a unit test for your change and make sure it passes.

Comment: Ah forgot about that. Pretty new to this, thank you!

Comment: So it was my changes that caused the errors, do you know by any chance what changes will cause the specific error?